# Why error messages doesn't show up in form validation in Flask?

Tags: python, html, flask

When I fill the form with data correctly, it creates the account and redirects to the login page - just as it should work. But when I fill the form with invalid data, eg. try to create a username with only one character - then an account won't be created (which is good), but also error messages don't appear. After many hours of experiments and changing the code, I still don't know what's causing that problem, especially when I used to create things like that using the same method and everything worked perfectly. **If you need more information/code please tell me and I'll edit the post.**

**Registration Form**

```
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Name',
                           validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)],
                           render_kw={"placeholder": "Username"})
    email = StringField('Email',
                        validators=[DataRequired(), Email()],
                        render_kw={"placeholder": "Email"})
    password = PasswordField('Password',
                             validators=[DataRequired()],
                             render_kw={"placeholder": "Password"})
    confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password',
                                     validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')],
                                     render_kw={"placeholder": "Confirm Password"})  # equal to password field
    submit = SubmitField('Sign Up')
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="registration-box">
<h1>Register</h1>
<form method="POST">
{{ form.hidden_tag() }}

<div class="textbox">
    {% if form.username.errors %}
        <div class="invalid-feedback">  
            {% for error in form.username.errors %}
                <span>{{ error }}</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% else %}
        <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        {{ form.username(class="text") }} 
    {% endif %}
</div>  

[... other forms for email, password etc...]
</div>
```